# Probability question- Intersection

Tags: probability

In a community, $70$% of families own a car, $30$% own a home, and $80$% own a car or home *but* not both. If a family is randomly chosen, what is the probability this family owns both a car and home?

So let $C$= own car, $H$=own home.
Then, $P(C)=.7$ and $P(H)=.3$.So I would need the intersection of C and H: $P(CH)=P(C)+P(H)-0.8=(0.7+0.3-0.8)=0.2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: @copper.hat I meant 30% own a home, sorry

Comment: @copper.hat: I followed my own advice and drew the picture! Yes, it is $10\%$.

Comment: Note to self: RTFQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am making a truly egregious mistake, I think your answer is wrong.

You have $P(H) = P(H \cap C) + P(H \setminus C)$ and $P(C) = P(C \cap H) + P(C \setminus H)$. Adding gives $P(H)+P(C) = 2 P(H \cap C) + (P(H \setminus C) + P(C \setminus H))$.

This gives $P(H \cap C) = \frac{1}{2} (P(H)+P(C) - (P(H \setminus C) + P(C \setminus H))$.

Hence $P(H \cap C) = 0.1$.

To illustrate: Suppose there are 10 families.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
& \overline{C} & C \\
\overline{H} & 1 & 6 \\
H & 2 &1
\end{array}$$

Comment: Oh okay, so I have to divide by 2 because the intersection is counted twice. Thanks!